# Добавить в регулярное выражение русские буквы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Вот есть такая регулярка:

```
"/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/"
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как еще добавить русские символы, а то только английские остаются.

*Обновление*

[[[[@ua6xh](/users/14126/ua6xh)](/users/14126/ua6xh)](/users/14126/ua6xh)](/users/14126/ua6xh) Хотел этой регуляркой проверять заголовок у статьи пред записью в базу данных.

```
"/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я()]/"
```

Это я свой переделал, правильно?

```
"/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$\sa-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я()]/"
```

Так пробел заменить?

*Обновление 2*

[[[[@ua6xh](/users/14126/ua6xh)](/users/14126/ua6xh)](/users/14126/ua6xh)](/users/14126/ua6xh) сделал вот так

```
"/[^.\,-_\'\"\@\?!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я()]/"
```

Но получилось вот что, при вводе слова "программист"

```
п�ог�амми��
```

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать этой регуляркой? может быть было проще взять `\W`? А по вопросу - просто допишите А-Яа-я

P.S.: пробел рекомендуется писать как `\s` - его так хотя бы видно в регулярке.

Comment: @Колямбий, юникод в регулярке включен (модификатор u стоит?)?

Comment: @Fike видно же, что нет. Тоже хотел подметить.

Comment: @Fike, @lampa скажите пожалуйста, как установить этот модификатор?

Comment: `/регулярка/u`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Спасибо. Сделал так:

```
"/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9А-Яа-я()]/u"
```

Работает.